# Search multiple workbooks for value counts in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

With World Cup in the near future, I am running a pool and would like to calculate stats.
I have a few hundred Excel Spreadsheets in on folder C:\WorldCup

Every Spreadsheet is the same
On every spreadsheet, the projected winner is in cell:  STEP2!N17

I would like to have a spreadsheet, that can search through the hundred XLS files and return a value count

Germany 34
Spain 20
USA 10
Italy 1

..etc

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer for the most part.  This will return all the values in that cell from closed workbooks

```
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()
Dim FolderName As String, wbName As String, r As Long, cValue As Variant
Dim wbList() As String, wbCount As Integer, i As Integer
    FolderName = "C:\Users\GARING\Documents\MyWorldCup\2014\2014Entries"
    ' create list of workbooks in foldername
    wbCount = 0
    wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls")
    While wbName <> ""
        wbCount = wbCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
        wbList(wbCount) = wbName
        wbName = Dir
    Wend
    If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ' get values from each workbook
    r = 0
    Workbooks.Add
    For i = 1 To wbCount
        r = r + 1
        cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "STEP2", "N17")
        Cells(r, 1).Formula = wbList(i)
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = cValue
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _
    wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
Dim arg As String
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    If Dir(wbPath & "\" & wbName) = "" Then Exit Function
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
        wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```